# How to compact a chmod UNIX command

Tags: shell, command-line, scripting, chmod

Is there anyway to compact the follow UNIX command:

```
chmod 755 scriptA.ksh | chmod 755 scriptB.ksh | chmod 755 scriptC.ksh | chmod 755 scriptD.ksh
```

The above command makes every KornShell (ksh) script executable, so the compacted command will be shorter in length and still make every ksh script executable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can send as many files as you want to `chmod`; you don't have to individually `chmod` each file if they all are being set to the same permission set.

You have many options here:

```
chmod 0755 *.ksh  # If you want to set these permissions on all *.ksh files
chmod 0755 script?.ksh  # If you want to set these permissions on all files named script[any single character].ksh
chmod 0755 scripta.ksh scriptb.ksh scriptc.ksh  # The plainest form - simply list the files
chmod 0755 script{a..c}.ksh  # Use brace expansion
```

In short, this is a cat with many skins to filet.  What you do *not* need to do, though, is pipe the output from one `chmod` into the standard input of the next.

Comment: Happy to have helped!

Answer (score 5):

Or adding to Graeme answer:

```
chmod 755 script{A,B,C,D}.ksh
```

If everyone has the same extension:

```
chmod 755 *.ksh
```

Comment: `chmod 755 *.ksh` worked great! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't get why you are piping one chmod to another, this seems pointless. The short answer to this is use shell globbing. For the files listed, this would be as simple as:

```
chmod 755 script?.ksh
```

Here the `?` matches any single character. `*` is more common to match multiple characters. There will be a full explanation of supported syntax in you shell manual.

#### Edit

Extending from comment below, one possibility would be to glob files you don't want to alter. In bash you use `!()`, eg:

```
chmod 755 !(*dont_break*).ksh
```

Comment: Well I made this question simple, in reality the scripts all have dissimilar names so I am not sure if globbing will work. So if the script names are: mainExtraction.ksh, updateStatus.ksh, removeHeader.ksh and endProcess.ksh then how can I compact this `chmod` command?

Comment: @Braiam pretty much has it with `*.ksh`. It really depends if there is anything else in your directory that you don't want to `chmod`